# Unity Touch phase returning incorrect results

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

In [Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity), I am attempting to use [`Touch`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Touch.html).

I am having non-stop issues with it and have decided to just try and get something simple working first.

Whenever i press the screen, i am expecting [`Touch.phase`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html) to return `TouchPhase.Began` every time. However, it will sometimes return `TouchPhase.Stationary` when touching the screen for the first time. I have also noticed that it will sometimes not call `TouchPhase.Ended` or `TouchPhase.Canceled` when the touch has left the screen. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my very simple code:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    if(Input.touchCount == 1) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch(touch.phase) {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            Debug.Log("Began: " + touch.figerId);
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Stationary:
            Debug.Log("Stationary");
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            Debug.Log("Moved");
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Canceled:
            Debug.Log("Canceled");
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Ended:
            Debug.Log("Ended");
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log("Default");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Touch.phase` is updated every frame, so you have to check it within the `Update()` method.

`FixedUpdate()` is only called every `x` frames (**fixed** framerate), that's the reason you are missing some of the touch phases.